# Cluedo and the Great Museum Caper characters

Tags: cluedo, cluedo-the-great-mystery-caper

Are there any other games in the Cluedo series that has the same characters? The only other one I could find was The Great Museum Caper...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.theartofmurder.com/ is probably the most comprehensive list I know of. It goes through all the editions, variants, spinoffs etc of Clue/Cluedo. Which are mostly the same game.

*The Great Museum Caper* is a 1991 variant in the US.

Comment: NICE! I wasnt aware of the puzzle series. Top marks.

Answer (score 1):

[Clue: The Card Game](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3269/clue-the-card-game) uses the same characters as the U.S. version of Clue: Colonel Mustard, Miss Scarlet, Professor Plum, Mr. Green, Mrs. White, and Mrs. Peacock.  In some ways, it's even more fun than the board game.

There's a [Cluedo card game](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17700/cluedo-card-game), too, but I can't personally vouch for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a long list of *official* Clue variants which can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluedo.  According to wikipedia, "The great-museum-caper" is not an official variant.

[This Answer was edited to improve it's value.]

Comment: Jo: it would greatly improve your answer if you could link to such a list, or include it in your answer.

Comment: Thank you.  Point taken.  I went to wikipidia and found a long list of both US and UK versions.